# How to add value two by two in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I want to make array that contain numbers into new array which has sum result of two by two.

For example, if there is number array like below

```
const arrayOne = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want to change it like below

```
const newArrayOne = [1, 5, 9, 13, 17]
```

other example is

```
const arrayTwo = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

const newArrayTwo = [21, 25, 29]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: @Liam-ReinstateMonica This is a new user, be kind please. The question itself is clear right?

Comment: Not really @A1rPun. I prefer my questions to include a `?`

Comment: I would prefer it if this question was closed as it violates multiple issues outlined in the [help]

Comment: I agree with Liam on closing it. But people tend to answer instead of explaining and flagging it

Answer (score 1):

You could take `flatMap` and return every second sum.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    pairs = array.flatMap((v, i, a) => i % 2 ? [] : [v + (a[i + 1] || 0)]);
    
console.log(pairs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with `for` iteration.

```
const arrayOne = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17]
const result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i+=2){
  const sum = arrayOne[i] + ((i + 1 < arrayOne.length) ? arrayOne[i + 1] : 0);
  result.push(sum);
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
let newArray = []
for (let i =0; i < array.length; i = i + 2){
  newArray.push(array[i] + array[i+1])
}
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

const output = arr.reduce((a, e, i) => (a[a.length - 1] += e, i % 2 && i !== arr.length - 1 && a.push(0), a), [0])
console.log(output)
```

Or, you could chunk the array, then add the elements together:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const output = arr.reduce((a, _, i) => (i % 2 === 0 && a.push(arr.slice(i, i + 2)), a), [])
  .flatMap(([a,b]) => a + b)
  
console.log(output)
```